# Pyplot Barchart: Bars not grouping around xticks properly

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Im trying to group four bars around the xticks in a bar chart. Heres some sample data (mind you, Im running this in Python 2.7) and my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xps_s1 = range(2008, 2019)
xps_s2 = range(2012, 2019)
xps_s3 = range(2013, 2019)
xps_s4 = range(2014, 2019)
yps_s1 = [94.6, 93.9, 93, 94.7, 94.6, 95.4, 95, 93.6, 93, 93.6, 92.2]
yps_s2 = [81.5, 90.2, 91.5, 94, 95, 94.3, 95.3]
yps_s3 = [83.9, 92.7, 93.3, 94.4, 94.4, 94.6]
yps_s4 = [90.6, 95, 94.8, 94, 93.9]

y_means = [94.6, 93.9, 93, 94.7, np.mean([81.5, 94.6]), 
           np.mean([83.9, 90.2, 95.4]), np.mean([92.7, 91.5, 95, 90.6]), 
           np.mean([93.3, 94, 93.6, 95]), np.mean([94.4, 95, 93, 94.8]), 
           np.mean([94.4, 94.3, 93.6, 94]), np.mean([91.4, 94.6, 95.3, 92.2, 93.9])]

fig = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(2007,2019), ylim=(75, 100))

w = 0.2
plt.xticks(np.arange(2008, 2019, step = 1))

rects1 = ax.bar([x-w for x in xps_s1], yps_s1, width=w, align="center",
                color='goldenrod', label='Sample1')

rects2 = ax.bar([x-w*2 for x in xps_s2], yps_s2, width=w, align="center",
                color='grey', label='Sample2')

rects3 = ax.bar([x+w for x in xps_s3], yps_s3, width=w, align="center",
                color='silver', label='Sample3')

rects4 = ax.bar([x+w*2 for x in xps_s4], yps_s4, width=w, align="center",
                color='thistle', label='Sample4')

mean_line =ax.plot(xps_s1,y_means, label='Overall', 
                       linestyle='-', color = "indianred")

legend = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

plt.show()
```

When I had three bars I set `w = 0.3`and the bars grouped nicely around the ticks (I had rects1 sit snuggly atop the tick, the other two right up against its flanks, the remaining .09 of width set the years apart)

Now with the above code they dont seem to be related to any tick really and they dont group properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your posted code run? I get `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`. Make sure people can run you code

Comment: Ah, sorry, had a typo in rects1... fixed

Comment: Again, you code is not working and again I would recommend to try copy pasting your code in a fresh notebook or editor and run it.

Comment: I have copied and pasted it, mustve been that some variables were still loaded. Cleared the variables and fixed the code. Again, sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `align='edge'` to simplify the calculations. Is this what you are trying to obtain?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xps_s1 = range(2008, 2019)
xps_s2 = range(2012, 2019)
xps_s3 = range(2013, 2019)
xps_s4 = range(2014, 2019)
yps_s1 = [94.6, 93.9, 93, 94.7, 94.6, 95.4, 95, 93.6, 93, 93.6, 92.2]
yps_s2 = [81.5, 90.2, 91.5, 94, 95, 94.3, 95.3]
yps_s3 = [83.9, 92.7, 93.3, 94.4, 94.4, 94.6]
yps_s4 = [90.6, 95, 94.8, 94, 93.9]

y_means = [94.6, 93.9, 93, 94.7, np.mean([81.5, 94.6]), 
           np.mean([83.9, 90.2, 95.4]), np.mean([92.7, 91.5, 95, 90.6]), 
           np.mean([93.3, 94, 93.6, 95]), np.mean([94.4, 95, 93, 94.8]), 
           np.mean([94.4, 94.3, 93.6, 94]), np.mean([91.4, 94.6, 95.3, 92.2, 93.9])]

fig = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(2007,2019), ylim=(75, 100))

w = 0.2
plt.xticks(np.arange(2008, 2019, step = 1))

rects1 = ax.bar([x-w for x in xps_s1], yps_s1, width=w, align="edge",
                color='goldenrod', label='Sample1')

rects2 = ax.bar([x-w*2 for x in xps_s2], yps_s2, width=w, align="edge",
                color='grey', label='Sample2')

rects3 = ax.bar([x for x in xps_s3], yps_s3, width=w, align="edge",
                color='silver', label='Sample3')

rects4 = ax.bar([x+w for x in xps_s4], yps_s4, width=w, align="edge",
                color='thistle', label='Sample4')

mean_line =ax.plot(xps_s1,y_means, label='Overall', 
                       linestyle='-', color = "indianred")

legend = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

plt.show()
```

[image]